# Загрузка изображений на сервер. Java

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

Здравствуйте, я пишу свой первый интернет магазин, и хочу что-бы избражение товара можно было закрузить прямо из админки сайта. Сервер Tomcat, БД MySQL, использую так же Spring MVC, Hibernate.
Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше все реализовать загрузку изображений на сервер через админку.

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет конкретики. Для загрузки можно использовать Spring MultipartResolver, хранить можно в ФС или БД. Отдавать можно через Tomcat или выделенный HTTP сервер (apache, nginx). Где находится форма загрузки в админке или нет, вообще ваше личное дело.Так о чем вопрос?

Comment: Ну так написано же что с админки сайта, а вот остальное я пока сам ищу, спсибо за вариант с Spring MultipartResolver, а хранить все будет в БД, отдавать скорее все что через tomcat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ничего особенного в загрузке изображений на сервер через админку нет. Во-первых, не важно из админки вы загружаете или с любой другой страницы. Во-вторых, загрузка изображения ничем не отличается от загрузки любого другого файла.

К сожалению, ваш вопрос слишком общий и не демонстрирует ваших попыток найти ответ самостоятельно. Что вы ожидали услышать в ответ? Полный листинг с кодом? Таких примеров достаточно в интернете.

Вот общий алгоритм:

- во view, в форму, добавить поле с типом `file`
- в контроллере получить этот файл (он будет доступен как аргумент с типом `MultipartFile`)
- провалидировать (пустой/не пустой, изображение или нет, может ли пользователь загружать файлы, не слишком ли файл большой и т.д.)
- получить массив байт (это и есть содержимое файла)
- записать эти байты в базу данных/на файловую систему/куда-то еще

Comment: Спсибо большое за хорошо изложенный ответ